# nested key-value pairs in form-urlencoded post request play WS

Tags: json, scala, post, playframework

I need to construct a data map of type `Map[String, Seq[String]]` for a `form-urlencoded` `POST` request in [Play WS library](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS).

The API I'm using, requires to submit the following form fields: token and an array of key-value pairs called `userPreferences`.

So, essentially, I need to convert a JSON like:

```
{
   token: 12345,
   userPreferences[0]: { key1: value1, key2: value2 },
   userPreferences[1]: { key2: value2 }

}
```

Into map of type `[String, Seq[String]]`.
What's the protocol? Will such approach work?

```
Map("token" -> Seq(12345), 
    "userPreferences[0]" -> Seq(key1, value1, key2, value2), 
    "userPreferences[1]" -> Seq(key2, value2))
```

How should I encode a nested JSON object as a key-value string? Do I just add pairs into the sequence converting to strings if necessary? How would the final query string look like?

I'm not using the whole Play framework, only this library for HTTP requests.

Might be a duplicate, but I've searched for almost an hour and haven't found an example.

Comment: Ok, I've tested the approach written above and it works. If you need to send single or multiple key-value pairs as one parameter, you just list them inside the sequence as Seq(key1, val1, key2, val2, etc).